# Redirect X window to a Docker container

Tags: centos, xorg, docker

I am trying to redirect X window on a Docker container, and I'm using xeyes to test it. I used an ubuntu docker image.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install x11-apps
```

Creating image:

```
docker build -t x11 .
```

before starting container, in order to allow all conections to X server:

```
xhost +
```

Testing X redirecting, and it was ok:

```
ssh -X localhost xeyes
```

Starting container:

```
docker run -it --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" --rm x11 xeyes
```

and got this output:

```
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

I also tried this way:

```
docker run -it --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix/X0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0:rw" --rm x11 xeyes
```

and got the same error:

```
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

I also tried the solution posted on [SSH X-Forward to X11 socket shared with docker container](https://superuser.com/questions/1420946/ssh-x-forward-to-x11-socket-shared-with-docker-container), but got the same result.

I am using Centos 7 as host.
Apparently, is something related to the X server on Centos. I tried it in a virtual machine with Kubuntu 19.04 with default installation, installed docker and it worked perfectly.

**UPDATED:**

Executing those commands as root:

```
ausearch -c 'xeyes' --raw | audit2allow -M my-xeyes
semodule -i my-xeyes.pp
```

it worked to all users!

Any idea why?

Comment: I'll guess its because of you being a regular user (probably UID and GUID = 1000) and container user is root (0, 0).  And I guess it doesn't matter but I mount: '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro'

Comment: I also tried it, but got the same result: `docker run -it --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix/X0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0:ro" --rm x11 xeyes` and returned `Error: Can't open display: :0`

Comment: Well, you are not running xeyes as another user. You are running it as root

Answer (score 1):

When using ubuntu:20.04

I found that -u 0 will solve the problem for podman, and -u $UID for docker.

```
$podman run -it -u 0 -e DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw podman-image xclock

$docker run -it -u $UID -e DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw docker-image xclock
```

On the docker file install x11-apps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With docker _-u 0_ and _-u $UID_ work well.